# How can i configure bootstrap in existing spring mvc project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an existing spring mvc project. It contains multiple views(jsp) and i want to improve its UI.
I want to integrate the project with bootstrap. How can bootstrap be configured to the project?
Can anyone tell how to configure? Where should the bootstrap css and js files should be stored in project and what modification should be done in dispatcher-servlet xml.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of using Spring MVC with twitter bootstrap. Hope this helps.

http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/twitter-bootstrap-with-spring-mvc